# Developing Android App without Using Support Library

Tags: android, android-support-library

Is there any way to develop android app without using Support Library.Bcoz i am having proble to download them,Eclipse could not find proper path to there??
Any one is it possible so?

Comment: You can develop but you will be unable to compile.    Maybe it is better to fix your download problems?

Comment: I have proble with SDK Manager to download them,do u have an idea about to download?

Comment: what is the problem you are having with the SDK manager?

Comment: Cant find support libraries,even as an Administrator.

Comment: It seems that there're some network problems in visiting Google in these days. Actually, you can copy the support package(/sdk root/extras/android) from other machines to your machine directly. Try to find and copy it from someone else.

Comment: not possible, how will you use the api.

Comment: Can you specify what type of error it shows, and also check is there any folder in your sdk's folder \extras\android named compatibility.

Comment: @ Chinmoy Debnath No,I dont find any folder like tht in SDK folder.

Comment: @Huang Also i tried with copy and past but not from another machine,but downloaded them from the web and created the folder extras paste in it,also this is not working.

Comment: If you have access to other sdk then goto folder extra then android and copy all item from compatibility / support if exists, then in your sdk's android folder create a folder name support paste the copied item, restart your eclips then i think your problem may be solved.

Comment: @ Chinmoy Debnath But what dou mean of other SDK??